# In Java, what is it called when I override methods during object initialization?

Tags: java

I'm looking for google-able terms. I'm just not sure how to describe this syntax:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Press Me");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("MyButton was pressed.");
    }
});
```

This syntax is new to me. Is there a name for this pattern/technique, and what is it?

Also, a follow up question for extra points :-) Why does this exist? It seems to me that this would result in some pretty cluttered code. Why not just extend `ActionListener`?

## Update

Forgive me, I meant to ask why you wouldn't **implement** `ActionListener`.

Comment: That's an anonymous inner class.

Comment: And it *is* implementing `ActionListener`.

Comment: Yes, it is. Let me clarify; Why not create a concrete class that extends ActionListener? That would strike me as resulting in much cleaner code.

Comment: anonymous inner class : a class with no name except its parent's.

Comment: @quakkels: Nothing stops you from creating a separate *named* (non-anon) class and using it instead of the anon one. It's like anon delegates in C# - you can always use a named one instead of an anon. And what's cleaner code very subjective, I for example consider anon. classes in Java and delegates in C# much cleaner than separate classes/delegates.

Comment: This is useful if you have a lot of buttons. You would need to create an own named class for each of these buttons; or implement some mapping-mechanism in a common action listener. With this approach, the code defining the button and handling its action is close to each other, enhencing readability in my opinion.

Comment: @quakkels: Also, anon classes in Java can capture local variables from  parent's scope, as long as they are marked as `final`. If you use a separate class you would somehow have to pass it params (via constructor for example), which further clutters the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called anonymous classing an interface.

Essentially, you are taking the Interface of ActionListener and making an instance that is only known by the class that encapsulates it.

You can't extend ActionListener because it is an interface. Extending a class means inheriting from it, and you can't inherit from interfaces in Java.

Interfaces are more customizable and are more like templates and cannot be standalone classes. Typically, there would be no purpose in having an interface be a standalone class.

Comment: This is correct, but you can also anonymously extend abstract classes, not only implement interfaces.

Comment: Forgive me. I meant to ask why you wouldn't implement ActionListener.

Comment: Good point. I honestly have never extended an anonymous class and thought mentioning it would be irrelevant, but you are definitely right.

Comment: You wouldn't implement ActionListener because this way you can have multiple versions of it in the same file. It is really more about convenience than anything.

Comment: actually, we could `extends` ActionListener if the subject who will extend is an `interface` too, of course this is purely concern extension since there would be no implementation until a class appear in the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 2):

As Rohit Jain said: Its an anonymous inner class.

Yes you could implement the `ActionListener` interface in a ordinary class in another File. I would prefer to do this when:

- I can give this thing a name
- I would like to reuse it somewhere else

An anonymous inner class does not need another file. You have the code, just right there where it is needed, but hinders code reuse.

Comment: Why can't you just make the ActionListener a field and reuse it on multiple buttons? That would be code reuse.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the where the code should be reused. Reuse in a distinct class may be OK, but to access the ActionListener from somewhere you have to raise the scope of it. I would tend to hide implementation details and not to make such a listener accessible to the outside world. But this depends on the concrete situation, trust boundaries and API design.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others already said, it's called anonymous inner classes. Here's an example/explanation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Sarajog

Answer (score 0):

The point of these is to avoid defining a whole new "real" class, taking up a whole file (yeah, big deal, I know), for something so trivial and useless for other purposes.  I.e. it's so coupled to what you're doing you want this low-attention mechanism instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that when you run javac, anonymous classes are compiled to a separate .class file from their containing class. So it kinda does still take up a whole new file.

Comment: Sure, it's purely a source file impact

Answer (score 0):

This is called an *anonymous inner class*. You are, in fact, implementing ActionListener AND instantiating this new anonymous class at the same time - the type name will be generated by the compiler. You would do this in cases where you only need the class once.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html